# ReSharper block under "case" label braces layout

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-formatting

I'm using ReSharper 10.0.2 with Visual Studio Community 2015.

It seems like I found a little bug on ReSharper not correctly placing braces   under "case" labels (I like to create blocks under case labels).

This is the result I want (K&R style):

[image]

And this is what I get when using either Ctrl+K+D or Ctrl+E+D (shortcuts for document code indenting / formatting) on VS:

[image]

I have the following settings on ReSharper options:

[image]

Also I have these settings on VS options itself:

[image]

Can anyone get the K&R style on blocks under case labels with the document code formatting / indentation shortcut? Or is it a bug?

Note: I do get the K&R style when pressing enter while writing the case block.

This is what happens when I press '{' after the colon (it places the block in the next line):

[image]

And this is what happens when I press ENTER inside the block (it places the open brace correctly):

[image]

Comment: Case statements don't require curly braces: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/06tc147t.aspx

Comment: I know, but, I like using blocks under case statements to define a local scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2015 Community just got updated and this problem disappeared.